# Sending and receiving multiple JSON literals via PHP sockets

Tags: php, json, sockets

I am trying send JSON data from one PHP script to another through sockets. The following is the client code

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
@socket_connect($socket, "localhost", 2429) or die("Connect could not be opened");

$arr = ["Hello", "I", "am", "a", "client"];
$count = 10;
while($count-- > 0) {
    $msg = json_encode(["msg" => $arr[rand(0, 4)]]); 
    // tried appending \n & \0
    // $msg .= "\0"; // "\n";
    echo "sending $msg \n";
    socket_write($socket, $msg, strlen($msg));
}
```

The following code is a piece of server that handles the reception:

```
$count = 0;
while(socket_recv($feed, $buf, 1024, 0) >= 1) {
    echo "Obj ".++$count." : $buf";
    // $obj = json_decode($buf); // error
}
```

The problem is, on the socket server side, the json_decode is unable to parse the data because of the following situation:

**Expected Output:**

```
Obj 1: {"msg":"I"}
Obj 2: {"msg":"a"}
Obj 3: {"msg":"a"}
Obj 4: {"msg":"I"}
Obj 5: {"msg":"a"}
Obj 6: {"msg":"client"}
Obj 7: {"msg":"am"}
Obj 8: {"msg":"am"}
Obj 9: {"msg":"am"}
```

**The output I get:**

```
Obj 1: {"msg":"I"}{"msg":"a"}{"msg":"a"}{"msg":"I"}
Obj 2: {"msg":"a"}{"msg":"client"}{"msg":"am"}{"msg":"am"}
Obj 3: {"msg":"am"}
```

I understand I need to tell the server `end of object` before sending the next one, but I do not know how. I tried to append "\n" and "\0" to tell the server end of stream, but it doesn't work. Please help me friends. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Some prepend the message with its length, others prefix it with a termination char, other both. I don't think the termination char strategy works well with JSON. Pass something like `11{"msg":"I"}`, then grab the number on the other side and push chars into a fixed-length array until it's full. Then just decode that and on to the next number.

Comment: Also, try single quotes when adding special chars so as to not get interpreted.

Comment: @nevvermind like read 11 first, then read 11 chars and next number and so on?

Comment: @nevvermind can you also please explain what happens to the last string? I mean, doesn't it get cut off when there's no space in buffer? And I might get partial json object?

Comment: each json literal you send will be prepended with its length. that includes the last one as well, doesn't it? that way you know beforehand which length you're expecting. check out these [two](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstring) [links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_Delimited_JSON). One deals with your exact situation, albeit not telling you _how_ exactly, but the format.

Comment: @nevvermind I know I can always use preg_split, but isn't there a straightforward way or something?

Comment: You're sending multiple messages in one 'envelope'. You need some way to know when one message ends and the next begins. A delimiter character or sequence is going to be hard to use because the delimiter character can appear inside a message (as a string). `preg_split` is also a no go because JSON is not a regular language. The _straightforward_ solution is to add a header to each message that indicates how long the message is. That is nevvermind's solution.

Comment: mmm, okay friends, guess there's no other way! can one of you post the answer so I close the case?

Comment: @nevvermind @Halcyon I figured another way: from the client send it like this: `socket_write($socket, $msg, 1024)`; instead of `strlen($msg)`, I used `1024` itself and its working perfectly as expected. I need to ask is it good practice?

Comment: No, it's not. You're safe on 127.0.0.1 or on a free bandwidth, but on heavy latencies for example, you'll have problems. Quoting from php.net: `socket_write() does not necessarily write all bytes from the given buffer. It's valid that, depending on the network buffers etc., only a certain amount of data, even one byte, is written though your buffer is greater. You have to watch out so you don't unintentionally forget to transmit the rest of your data.` Aka sending 1024 bytes doesn't guarantee 1024 bytes _will_ be sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try adding a length header, as that's the safest way to go when strings are involved.

Your client needs to send that information, so a slight change to your original code is in order: `$msg = strlen($msg) . $msg;` (right after `$msg = json_encode(["msg" => $arr[rand(0, 4)]]);`.

Then, assuming `$socket` is opened, try this as the server code (don't forget to close your sockets):

```
$lengthHeader = '';
$jsonLiteral = '';

while ($byte = socket_read($socket, 1)) { // reading one number at a time

    echo "Read $byte\n"; 

    if (is_numeric($byte)) { //

        $lengthHeader .= $byte;

    } else if ($lengthHeader) {

        echo "JSON seems to start here. So...\n";

        $nextMsgLength = $lengthHeader - 1; // except the current one we've just read (usually "[" or "{")

        echo "Will grab the next $nextMsgLength bytes\n";

        if (($partialJson = socket_read($socket, $nextMsgLength)) === false) {
            die("Bad host, bad!");
        }

        $jsonLiteral = $byte . $partialJson;

        $lengthHeader = ''; // reset the length header

        echo "Grabbed JSON: $jsonLiteral\n";
    } else {
        echo "Nothing to grab\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I read the whole string and used `preg_match` and `substr` and accomplished the same ;) but this is awesome and better. Thanks

Answer (score -3):

you use socket_write function for other socket. When you add EOF char, is just for other socket recv. But you must know EOF char with that socket_write for your recv and explode it.